# Different runtime behavior depending on how the program is started (terminal vs. Qt Creator)

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt-creator

I have a problem with the runtime behavior of my program, depending on how I start it (Terminal or Qt Creator).

It's a short program to match two images using openCV. Internally, openCV probably does some optimizations, so multiple cores are used / can be used when running.

When I start the program from the terminal, I can observe that all cores are used. => fast program

If I start the program directly from Qt Creator, only one kernel will be used. => slow program

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?
I created the binary file with Qt Creator, so why do I get two different behaviors, depending on my execution method?

Here is an example:

```
//main.cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

void compute(Mat &img, vector<KeyPoint> &kVec, Mat &dMat) {
    StarFeatureDetector featureDectector(16, 5, 10, 8, 5);
    featureDectector.detect(img, kVec);
    BriefDescriptorExtractor descriptorExtractor(64);
    descriptorExtractor.compute(img, kVec, dMat);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Mat img1 = cv::imread("img1.pgm", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat img2 = cv::imread("img2.pgm", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    Mat dMat1, dMat2;
    vector<KeyPoint> kVec1, kVec2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;

        compute(img1, kVec1, dMat1);    // compute Key-Points first image
        compute(img2, kVec2, dMat2);    // compute Key-Points second image

        vector< vector<DMatch> > cVec;
        BFMatcher matcher(NORM_HAMMING, false);
        matcher.knnMatch(dMat1, dMat2, cVec, 2);
    }
}

#.pro file
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG += c++14
TARGET = test
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += opencv
include(3rdparty.pri) #openCV include
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Comment: What if you start program from IDE in debug mode?

Comment: I tryed a "release" and a "debug" kit, but it's the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QtCreator execution environment can have different set of used paths. 
For example you can have your own Qt build that not reflected in system PATH variable. In that case you can build your program and run inside QtCreator as well. But system command line environment can use another Qt libraries, that reflected in PATH variable. 
I suppose your have same issue. Possibly not with Qt libraries.

Comment: thank you for your answer! How can I check these different PATH variables? I'm working on a linux system.

Comment: I can advise you compare list of linked libraries in runtime. For every case. But I don't know how to check that list for runtime applications. 

List of environment variables  for QtCreator places in "Project" tab. List of variables for command line, runtime you can see with "export" command. Also you can use "ldd" program to check list of libraries that will attached when command line mode.
But I think that not trivial way to found solution. 
Use first suggestion please. You will see end effect of all environment  variables.

Comment: Is there no easier way? I think it's just a Qt Creator configuration thing. If I start my Qt Creator and it only gets "access" to one kernel, every program startet from Qt Creator also has only access to one kernel. That means qt just has to get more execution rights. Is this possible or am I thinking too easy?

Comment: Does it maybe depend on my openCV version/build? Currently I'm playing around with another project, which uses a different openCV version. In this example all kernels are used.

Comment: yes, that may be reason. Check another and stable version.